# Bash loop behaving unexpectedly

Tags: bash, shell

I was working on a simple daemon example and noticed that the following command prints same value of time on every iteration.

```sh
/bin/bash -c "while true; do echo `date`; sleep 1; done"
```

**Output:**

```sh
Wed Dec 25 08:00:47 UTC 2013
Wed Dec 25 08:00:47 UTC 2013
Wed Dec 25 08:00:47 UTC 2013
```

However, If I put the above code in a script and then run the script, it gives the expected output.

```sh
#!/bin/bash
while true; do
   echo `date`
   sleep 1
done
```

**Output:**

```sh
Wed Dec 25 08:02:58 UTC 2013
Wed Dec 25 08:02:59 UTC 2013
Wed Dec 25 08:03:00 UTC 2013
```

How is this possible? Is this the expected output?

Comment: `/bin/bash -c "while true; do date; sleep 1; done"` will give the correct output.

Comment: Related: [Difference between single and double quotes in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6697753/6862601).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It behaves exactly as expected. The `date` substitution is performed by caller bash, not by callee. Alter the command this way:

```
/bin/bash -c 'while true; do echo `date`; sleep 1; done'
```

and you get the behavior expected by you.

**The difference is in single and double quoted strings - the latter ones are subject to the *parameters expansion* and *command substitution***

Comment: Nit: What OP is seeing is not parameter expansion, but rather *[command substitution](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/CommandSubstitution)*. [More on quotes.](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes)